# Is this proof of $X\times Y=\emptyset\iff X=\emptyset \lor Y=\emptyset$ rigorous enough wrt predicate logic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

I've seen a similar question, but this question is concerned with my proof.

Here is my proof.

$\Rightarrow$)
Assume $X\neq\emptyset\land Y\neq\emptyset$.

$X\neq\emptyset\land Y\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow\exists x\colon x\in X\land \exists y\colon y\in Y \Rightarrow x_0\in X\land y_0\in Y\Rightarrow (x_0,y_0)\in X\times Y\Rightarrow X\times Y\neq\emptyset$.

Thus, we have a contradiction.

$\Leftarrow$)

$X\times Y\neq \emptyset\Rightarrow\exists s\colon s\in X\times Y\Rightarrow s_0\in X\times Y\Rightarrow\exists x\exists y\colon x\in X\land y\in Y\land s_0=(x,y)\Rightarrow x_0\in X\land y_0\in Y\land s_0 = (x_0,y_0)\Rightarrow X\neq\emptyset\land Y\neq\emptyset$

Are all the steps in the proof justified? There may be subtle moments not stated explicitly I might have missed. I want to make the proof as rigorous as possible, so if some implications require additional argumentation, could you point that out and explain?

P.S. Yes, I'm a little meticulous. Sorry for that.

Comment: [Please do not use images to convey key mathematical information not otherwise present in your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, sorry, I will edit the question. I thought the information in the picture was irrelevant other than within the context.

Comment: Looks good to me. ( Besides a typo, you probably meant Y ≠  ∅ , on the first line) Note: Proofs without any English  in them are of course valid, but for readability you'll find that English is often used to express the ideas, in a proof, and to guide the reader by stating your intentions. Of course, its great  to just do the pure formalism as well, as a learning exercise. But, its also useful to be able to express the gist of an argument in English, to gain a broader understanding beyond the pure logic formalism. After all, we think in informal language.

Comment: @Michael Carey, thank you! Yes, that was a typo. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done this proof differently:
$ X \times Y=\emptyset \iff \forall x,y; (x,y) \notin X \times Y \iff x\notin X \lor y\notin Y (\forall x,y) \iff X=\emptyset \lor Y=\emptyset$
$X \times Y$ is defined as $\{(x,y) \vert x \in X \land y \in Y \}$ therefore it is impossible for an element of $X \times Y$ not to be a pair.

Comment: $X\times Y=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $\forall t, t\notin X\times Y$, which is a stronger condition than all $t$ *that are pairs* not being in $X\times Y$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I've added the definition I've used for the proof.